# Add bootsrap multi-select inside jquery databales dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

I am facing trouble adding a bootstrap multi-select inside jquery `datatable` dom. I am using this [example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html) for adding a custom dom element within the jquery `datatable` container. It works fine for the normal `bootstrap select` but when I try to add bootstrap multi-select then it doesn't work as expected. You can see the image below.
[image]

**Here is my code for this piece of work**

```
$(this).DataTable({
       "language": (language == "de") ? DTlanguage : false,
       "bSort": false,
       lengthMenu: [
                [25, 50, 100, 500, -1],
                ['25 ' + window.jsTranslations.rows + '', '50 ' + window.jsTranslations.rows + '', '100 ' + window.jsTranslations.rows + '', '500 ' + window.jsTranslations.rows + '', window.jsTranslations.show_all]
            ],
            "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip', // this piece of code is responsible for adding multiselect

            buttons: buttons,
        });
        $("div.toolbar").html(`
            <select class="form-control multiselect document-templates" multiple="multiple" name="document_template[]">
            </select> // this piece of code is responsible for adding multiselect
        `);
```

Comment: Need to do it in a render callback

Comment: Can you please give a coding example

Comment: This sort of works - though I'm not sure what you need to pass to the `multiselect` I'm afraid: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/o7n86qjs/

Answer (score 1):

Goodness me, that period between Xmas and the New Year can be boring. I got to playing with this some more after adding my comment above and decided to give it a go. This code seems to be providing what you need, though without knowing your exact use case I might be wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const example = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: '<"row"<"col"<"toolbar">><"col"f>>rtip',
    initComplete: function(settings, json) {
      const columns = this.api().columns(2).data().eq(0).sort().unique().toArray()
      const select = $('<select></select>', {
        id: 'example-select',
        multiple: 'multiple'
      })
      columns.forEach(el => select.append($('<option></option>', {
        value: el,
        text: el
      })))
      $('div.toolbar').append(select);
      $('#example-select').multiselect({
        onChange: function() {
          const selected = $('#example-select option:selected').toArray().map(opt => $(opt).val()).join('|')
          example.column(2).search(selected, true, false).draw()
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Rather than use the draw callback I originally tried, this kicks everything off at the start. Make note of the `dom` option as that tells DataTables to add a div with the class of `row`, within which are the multi-select as well as the regular search input - both of which are in divs with the class of `col`.

We get the unique values from the location column and add them to a select which is initialised as a multi-select. It has a `onChange` event listener which grabs all the selected options and uses them in a regex search of the DataTable.

Working example here: https://repl.it/@annoyingmouse/Multiselect#script.js